# Possible to delete rejected build of IOS app in App Store in 2019?

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple rejected my app over yet another picayune, easily fixed thing which I would rather not go into and my build count keeps going up. Is there a way to just delete this build in App Store Connect on the App Store, so I don't keep accumulating and incrementing build versions?

There are a lot of questions about this on SO going way back but a lot of disagreement and many of the accepted answers are very old. The closest thing I can find is hover over the build number and a red minus sign is supposed to appear but I can't get it do that.

When I hover over the build version in Activity, I don't see any way to delete it. If I click on it, I see more detailed information but also no way to delete.

Comment: Do you mean remove the build from the list of uploaded builds or remove the selection status of the build you are submitting?  No to the former, yes to the latter

Comment: The former. Was hoping to just delete that build and upload another one with same build # to prevent what seems like unnecessary accumulation of never-used builds.

Comment: No, if you have uploaded build X, you can't upload that build number again.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to delete/remove the build. Below is a screenshot from an app that was recently rejected. The minus button is still there.

Once you remove the build you can select a new one and resubmit.

[Remove build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krQXh.png)

Comment: was the minus button just there or did you have to hover or otherwise do something to get it to appear

Comment: you have to hover the build to make the button appear.

Comment: Makes sense.  Did not work for me, however.  I will try with a different browser.